# How to retrieve visual web part properties programmatically? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, asp.net

In my properties I have a properties called `Kompania` and it is a dropdown properties. How can I retrieve the current properties for `Kompania`

Please help me!

Comment: You will get some reference from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188019/Creating-Visual-Web-Part-Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the properties of a visual WebPart programmatically, you can refer to the following code for the WebPart at this [article](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2013/05/visual-webpart-programmatically-update.html).

```
public enum CityEnum { Manila, Berlin, Auckland, Zurich };
public static CityEnum SampleDropDown;
[Category("Extended Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Sample Drop Down"),
WebDescription("Please Choose a Sample DropDown")]
public CityEnum _SampleDropDown
{
    get { return SampleDropDown; }
    set { SampleDropDown = value; }
}
```

then on Page_Load() method use this line

```
Label1.Text = yourclass._SampleDropDown;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/64482)

Comment: @Dikesh : ok will keep it in mind from next time. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: useless for me!

Comment: useless ?? in what sense ?

Comment: @DebugCode after a deep study I realized that this was the exactly what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code below class definition.

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Project ID"),
WebDescription("Enter Project Number"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
Category("Project Settings")]
public string ProjectID { get; set; }
```

To get the property value in code,  you should use the “ProjectID” variable that defined as

```
public string ProjectID { get; set; }
```

You can also check detail steps at [Create Custom WebPart Property for SharePoint Visual WebPart](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/23/create-custom-web-part-properties-for-visual-webpart-sharepoint2013/)